# WPF TextBlock won't update despite PropertyChanged

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding

I'm writing an MVVM app and I'm trying to include a status bar at the bottom. I've set up the view and view model, which are supposed to track the status of the app's Logger class, which is a singleton for ease of use.

View:

```
<UserControl x:Class="SynthEBD.UC_StatusBar"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:SynthEBD"
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         d:DataContext="{d:DesignInstance Type=local:VM_StatusBar}"
         d:DesignHeight="450" d:DesignWidth="800">
<Grid >
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <TextBlock Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Text="{Binding Path=DispString}" Foreground="{Binding Path=FontColor}" FontSize="18" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
</Grid>
```

View Model:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Media;

namespace SynthEBD
{
    public class VM_StatusBar : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public VM_StatusBar()
        {
            this.DispString = "";
            this.FontColor = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Green);
            this.SubscribedLogger = Logger.Instance;
            this.SubscribedLogger.PropertyChanged += RefreshDisp;
        }

        public string DispString { get; set; }
        private Logger SubscribedLogger { get; set; }
        public SolidColorBrush FontColor { get; set; }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        public void RefreshDisp(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            this.DispString = SubscribedLogger.StatusString;
            this.FontColor = SubscribedLogger.StatusColor;
        }
    }
}
```

Logger:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Media;

namespace SynthEBD
{
    public sealed class Logger : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        private static Logger instance;
        private static object lockObj = new Object();

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        public VM_RunButton RunButton { get; set; }
        public string StatusString { get; set; }
        public string LogString { get; set; }

        public SolidColorBrush StatusColor { get; set; }

        public SolidColorBrush ReadyColor = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Green);
        public SolidColorBrush WarningColor = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Yellow);
        public SolidColorBrush ErrorColor = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red);
        public string ReadyString = "Ready To Patch";

        private Logger()
        {
            this.StatusColor = this.ReadyColor;
            this.StatusString = this.ReadyString;
        }

        public static Logger Instance
        {
            get
            {
                lock (lockObj)
                {
                    if (instance == null)
                    {
                        instance = new Logger();
                    }
                }
                return instance;
            }
        }

        public static void LogError(string error)
        {
            Instance.LogString += error + "\n";
        }

        public static void LogErrorWithStatusUpdate(string error, ErrorType type)
        {
            Instance.LogString += error + "\n";
            Instance.StatusString = error;
            switch (type)
            {
                case ErrorType.Warning: Instance.StatusColor = Instance.WarningColor; break;
                case ErrorType.Error: Instance.StatusColor = Instance.ErrorColor; break;
            }
        }

        public static void TimedNotifyStatusUpdate(string error, ErrorType type, int durationSec)
        {
            LogErrorWithStatusUpdate(error, type);

            var t = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
            {
                Task.Delay(durationSec * 1000).Wait();
            });
            t.Wait();
            ClearStatusError();
        }
        public static void ClearStatusError()
        {
            Instance.StatusString = Instance.ReadyString;
            Instance.StatusColor = Instance.ReadyColor;
        }
    }

    public enum ErrorType
    {
        Warning,
        Error
    }
}
```

I am intentionally triggering the Logger.TimedNotifyStatusUpdate() function, and even though I can see a breakpoint being reached within VM_StatusBar.RefreshDisp(), the actual on-screen string and color never change (https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Baep.jpg). I don't see any failed bindings, so I don't understand why the view is not updating. Thanks for any advice!

Edit: I also tried explicitly triggering the PropertyChanged event instead of relying on PropertyChanged.Fody as follows, but the on-screen result was identical.

```
public class VM_StatusBar : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public VM_StatusBar()
        {
            this.DispString = "";
            this.FontColor = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Green);
            this.SubscribedLogger = Logger.Instance;
            this.SubscribedLogger.PropertyChanged += RefreshDisp;
        }

        public string DispString
        {
            get { return _dispString; }
            set
            {
                if (value != _dispString)
                {
                    _dispString = value;
                    OnPropertyChanged("DispString");
                }
            }
        }
        private string _dispString;
        private Logger SubscribedLogger { get; set; }
        public SolidColorBrush FontColor { get; set; }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        protected void OnPropertyChanged(PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
            if (handler != null)
                handler(this, e);
        }

        protected void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
        {
            OnPropertyChanged(new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }

        public void RefreshDisp(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            this.DispString = SubscribedLogger.StatusString;
            this.FontColor = SubscribedLogger.StatusColor;
            string debugBreakHere = "";
        }
    }
```

Comment: Merely setting the property value is not enough. You have to fire the `PropertyChanged` event whenever the setter is called.

Comment: I'm using PropertyChanged.Fody so I think this should be handled for me (https://github.com/Fody/PropertyChanged). All of my other bindings update correctly without having to manually fire the event. Is there something about this specific configuration that requires it?

Comment: Do you call `TimedNotifyStatusUpdate` on the UI-Thread? If it's called from a different thread the property change notification goes nowhere

Comment: What happens if you, test wise, remove the to the whole `TaskFactory.StartNew` block?
It's an async delay awaited in synchronous blocking manner...

Comment: How is the DataContext set? Are you sure the binding resolves? You should enable data binding tracing and check the output window of the debugger for binding errors.

Comment: @BionicCode bindings resolve. The image linked proves it

Comment: @lidqy Raising PropertyChanged on a different thread than the UI thread is fine. It's marshalled by the binding engine (what is not the case for the CollectionChanged event).

Comment: @BionicCode ok. i had an issue with resetting Mouse.OverrideCursor on a non UI-Thread which didn't throw but also didn't work, worked when dispatched. But that's not IPNC related, true...

Comment: @lidqy Yes, the thread from which the property is chnaged doesn't matter. But blocking the I thread does indeed.

Comment: @APiranha How is `VM_StatusBar` created and bound to the UserControl? If it was instantiated multiple times, it would explain why bindings seem to work, the relevant code is executed, pc-event is raised - but still nothing happens - because it all happens in the wrong instance of the VM...
The code that creates the VM instance (hopefully not instances) and the one that makes the VM the statusbar controls DataContext isn't shown in the provided code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should never call `Task.Wait` on a `Task` object. Always `await` it in order to allow it to complete asynchronously. From your posted code it looks like you are blocking the UI thread, thus stealing resources that are needed to update the surface (rendering). `Task.Wait` is a ticket to a deadlock.
Also, prefer `Task.Run` over `Task.Factory`.

Turning your blocking code into non-blocking shoulkd do the trick:

```
public static async Task TimedNotifyStatusUpdateAsync(string error, ErrorType type, int durationSec)
{
  LogErrorWithStatusUpdate(error, type);

  Task t = Task.Run(async () =>
  {
    // Calling Wait on the Task blocks this thread
    //Task.Delay(durationSec * 1000).Wait();

    // Instead 'await' the Task to free resources
    await Task.Delay(durationSec * 1000);
  });

  // Await the Task to allow the UI thread to render the view
  // in order to show the changes
  await t;   

  ClearStatusError();
}
```

Then call the method from another `async Task` method using `await`:

```
private async Task CallTimedNotifyStatusUpdateAsync()
  => await TimedNotifyStatusUpdateAsync();
```

Note that wrappping an async method into `Task.Run` is generally not a good idea. The correct implementation of `TimedNotifyStatusUpdateAsync` would be:

```
public static async Task TimedNotifyStatusUpdateAsync(string error, ErrorType type, int durationSec)
{
  LogErrorWithStatusUpdate(error, type);

  // Await the Task to allow the UI thread to render the view
  // in order to show the changes     
  await Task.Delay(durationSec * 1000);

  ClearStatusError();
}
```

Comment: Beautiful, got it working by implementing your code as follows:

catch{
Logger.Instance.CallTimedNotifyStatusUpdateAsync("Could not delete file at " + this.SelectedHeightConfig.SourcePath, ErrorType.Warning, 5);}

May I ask why in your sample code you made CallTimedNotifyStatusUpdateAsync private? I had to make it public so that it could be accessible from the calling function. Am I supposed to call CallTimedNotifyStatusUpdateAsync itself from another function that is public?

Comment: No, there was no intend behind it. The method CallTimedNotifyStatusUpdateAsync is completely made up. I just introduced it to show how to call the modified TimedNotifyStatusUpdateAsync method. Hence the prefixx *Call...* (CallTimedNotifyStatusUpdateAsync).